# Strange requests going to my webserver, are they malicious?

Tags: php, node.js, apache, nginx, server

I have been getting some really weird requests going to my webserver from various proxies.

```
[2021:8:6:8:18:23] new POST request for /api/jsonws/invoke from [ip redacted] took 2ms
[2021:8:6:8:18:23] new POST request for /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php from [ip redacted] took 2ms
[2021:8:6:8:18:25] new GET request for /index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21 from [ip redacted] took 2ms
[2021:8:6:8:18:25] new GET request for /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php from [ip redacted] took 2ms
[2021:8:6:8:18:28] new POST request for /mifs/.;/services/LogService from [ip redacted] took 2ms
[2021:8:6:8:18:28] new GET request for /?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm from [ip redacted] took 2ms
[2021:8:6:8:18:29] new GET request for /wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/readme.txt from [ip redacted] took 2ms
[2021:8:6:8:18:30] new GET request for /console/ from [ip redacted] took 2ms
[2021:8:6:8:18:31] new POST request for /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml from [ip redacted] took 4ms
[2021:8:6:8:18:34] new GET request for /_ignition/execute-solution from [ip redacted] took 2ms
```

None of these pages exist on my website, it looks like a bot is trying to exploit some misconfigurations in apache/nginx. My backend is in nodejs.

Are these requests malicious? Should I be concerned?

Comment: Seems like someone targets your website with some sort of vulnerability scanner...

Comment: the interwebs are full of vulnerable sites (mostly wordpress sites which are not updated or use nulled plugins/themes), computers, iot's etc etc, this traffic would be a hacked site or device which is part of a botnet etc scouring the web for things to enumerate, its nothing to worry about unless your running a vulnerable never updated, full of nulled plugins or themed site, then in your site just becomes another scanner/bot/spammer in the network after a db, account, log history dump back to the c&c.. you could use fail2ban to block ips but your not blocking a specific attacker, so no point